# Jenkins looses certificates each time we upgrade JDK

Tags: jenkins

We're using Jenkins to run tests against DB over TLS. For that JDK on Jenkins node requires DB certificate to be installed in the keystore.

We have added certificate to JDK keystore and it worked fine until we upgraded minor version of JDK (from 1.8.11 to 1.8.45). It looks like every time we upgrade JDK, keystore is refreshed. Is there a way to avoid reinstalling certificates every time we upgrade JDK?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be quicker answered if posted to a Jenkins forum?